# Return the name of the account with account id

Tags: apex, soql, account

Would you help me please~

I want to return the name of the account with the string parameter (Account's ID) handed over from JS!

I converted the id of the account to string in JS and handed it over to the apex class.

which is **String accountIdList** and it has data looks like `a071s0000093T8hAAE, a071s0000093RDzAAM, a071s0000092WKRAA2`

So i convert String accountIdList to List which is `List<String> accountIdLists = accountIdList.split(',');`

And i was supposed to turn for loop and add this ID to Set a = new Set(); I wanted to add it here, but it doesn't work!

I made Account list and wanted to return account1 and send the Id and Name of account back to JS!
`List<Account> account1= [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account Where id in:a];`

What should I do? Please help me, masters!

here is my hole code.

```
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<Account> getChatterAccountName(String accountIdList) {

  List<String> accountIdLists = accountIdList.split(',');

  Set<Id> a = new Set<Id>();

  for(String s :accountIdLists){
     a.add(s);
  } 


  List<Account> account1= [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account Where id in:a];


  return account1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unnecessarily complicated code, just pass in the list directly:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Account[] getChatterAccountName(Id[] accountIds) {
  return [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountIds];
}
```

In your JavaScript, make sure you are passing in the values as an Array, and Apex will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: !! Thank you very much sir!! I made it~ your code is works!!